# Pipe in Ping command output

Tags: linux, unix, networking, pipe, ping

Ping command output:

```
PING google.com (216.58.197.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
......
--- google.com ping statistics ---
53 packets transmitted, 28 received, 47% packet loss, time 687ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.360/57.587/88.878/9.458 ms, pipe 8, ipg/ewma 13.220/57.967 ms
```

The above output shows the statistics. Here, what is the pipe refers to ?

Answer (score 1):

Its the count of maximum number of ICMP echo request packets pending responses.
See https://serverfault.com/questions/587730/what-does-pipe-number-mean-in-ping-output for information about the pipe in ping.

Comment: I already saw that answer. But, unanswered ICMP echo request packet means, (Number of echo request packet sent - Number of echo reply packet arrived). Is it correct ? If it is correct, Here 53-28=25. So, expected pipe value will be 25. But how it is 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the link provided by RaviTezu, check the **last** answer. It's not the number of packets lost. Rather, it's maximum number of outstanding requests that are not acknowledge at some point of time, but are eventually acknowledged.

Comment: So, if the echo reply packet doesn't comes within the minimal interval of time, it is considered as packet loss. But eventually if it is received, it is considered as pipe. Is is right?